# Our DB has about 2000 tables, shall I use ORM framework?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm getting involved in a project that is a very old system and we have to rewrite it to java. Therefore we need to determine what frameworks will be used. we are going to use JPA and hibernate, but the DB has about 2000 tables... it will cause too many entities, metamodels, and repositories.

So the question is shall I use JPA/hibernate in this project? I'm afraid about the performance of initializing, developing and the loading of memory. can anyone give some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the mixed technique will be optimal: object/entities + queries using the ORM (HQL/JPQL). No need to make mapping every table in existence. It is necessary to audit all tables, their sizes and their needs for work in your application. Estimate which of them will require a lot of memory during loading objects/entities. For large size tables or tables that not contains large business logic use queries. It is possible that some tables are not required to be connected. Will be right to use the read strategy **LAZY** instead of **EAGER** when it possible as well.

Perhaps in your legacy database the main part of logic is placed on the stored procedures. This often happens and this leads to great difficulties during the transition to ORM-abstractions. In this case, it is rational to leave some part of this logic in its original form at least temporarily.

You can also use **only JDBC**, but this will lead to parallel programming in Java and SQL.

**Finally**: Don't worry, for performance problems appearance, there is no need for a champion-sized database at all.

**Upd.**

- I can advise not to read the big recordset (including use **Pagination**), so that there are not
  many objects in the collections received.
- Read single table's fields selectively through queries instead of
  reading the entire table.
- Also create 'light' classes versions, where possible , with reduced
  numbers of fields to facilitate entity loading.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I might use the mixed technique, however, after my investigation, there are approximately 1000 entities will be mapped to the tables, but I don't want to use the only JDBC.  I am considering spring data JPA as well, what do think?

Comment: I have added some points in my answer. On my biggest project (big bank on DB Oracle 11) it was JDBC, but in any case you have to try...